# Group by a column without including in Select list

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, insert-into

I need to group by multiple columns and insert the results into a table but one of the columns I need to group by isn't to be inserted, such as the following...

```
INSERT INTO tbl (fld1, fld2, fld3, fld4)
SELECT DISTINCT fld1, fld2, fld3, fld4, fld5
```

It won't let me insert the records because of the extra column that I need grouped. Is there a potential workaround for this?

Comment: You do know that you may get multiple identical columns inserted this way, do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tbl (fld1, fld2, fld3, fld4)
SELECT fld1, fld2, fld3, fld4
GROUP BY fld1, fld2, fld3, fld4, fld5
```